# Sencha GXT themebuilder 3.1.0 Beta does not work with Sencha Gxt 3.1.0

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, themes, gxt

I built a theme with the themebuilder from Sencha GXT 3.1.0-Beta. It works well if I use Sencha GXT 3.1.0-Beta in my application, but if I use Sencha GXT 3.1.0 it doesn't work anymore.

I get the following error:

```
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in jar:file:/D:/maven/repository/de/company/theme-0.0.1.jar!/de/company/theme/client/base/toolbar/Css3ToolBarAppearance.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 20: The type Css3ToolBarAppearance must implement the inherited abstract method BoxLayoutContainer.BoxLayoutContainerAppearance.render(SafeHtmlBuilder)
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 20: The type Css3ToolBarAppearance must implement the inherited abstract method HBoxLayoutContainer.HBoxLayoutContainerAppearance.moreIcon()
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 20: The type Css3ToolBarAppearance must implement the inherited abstract method HBoxLayoutContainer.HBoxLayoutContainerAppearance.moreButtonStyle()
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/toolbar/ToolBar.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 39: Rebind result 'de.company.theme.client.base.toolbar.Css3ToolBarAppearance' could not be found
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/maven/repository/de/company/0.0.1/theme-0.0.1.jar!/de/company/theme/client/base/Css3ThemeAppearance.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 58: The method moreIcon() of type Css3ThemeAppearance must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/sencha/gxt/core/client/resources/ThemeStyles.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 29: Rebind result 'de.company.theme.client.base.Css3ThemeAppearance' could not be found
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/toolbar/PagingToolBar.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 217: Rebind result 'de.company.client.base.toolbar.Css3ToolBarAppearance' could not be found
```

Does anyone have a hint what to do?

Comment: Have you tried to update the the themebuilder also? I don't think, that the themes from older version of the themebuilder will work with the a new GXT version.

Answer (score 0):

The versions must be used together - 3.1.0-beta of the themebuilder cannot work any version of gxt other than 3.1.0-beta. Regenerate the theme with the same version of the themebuilder as the gxt version you are using.

By and large, versions are not so restricting - 3.1.0 and 3.1.1 should be compatible for example (though I can't guarantee that this is 100% so, since some quirk of behavior might be dependent between these versions), but the -beta version is, well, a beta - it has bugs, and breaking changes sometimes need to be made after a beta and before the final release.

Comment: Where can I get the "normal" version of the thembuilder? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Where did you get GXT itself? It should be available from the same place, as part of the download?

Comment: I included it from the Mavenrepository.

Comment: The latest gpl download can be found here http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/license/ (GXT 3.1.1-gpl at this time). Look for the download button.